# Result of comparing a null string in C

Tags: c, arrays, null, comparison, string-comparison

I have two char arrays in a C program:

```
char stored_pass[15] = "steveone"
char pass[15] = "\0"
```

When running `strcmp(stored_password, pass)` to compare the two I get the result that they are equal (==0).

I do not really understand why that's the case.

Can anyone please explain it to me? I looked up the difference between an empty and null-terminated string but did not really find an answer.

The problem appears to be in the authenticate method.

Source Code of the total C Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Execute any shell command
void execute(char *cmd)
{
   execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-p", "-c", cmd, NULL);
}

void sanitise(char *password)
{
  int i,j;
  char tmp[15];

  // remove non-alphabet  characters from passwords
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i < 15; ++i) 
    if(password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z') {
      tmp[j]=password[i];
      ++j;
    } else break;
  tmp[j] = '\0';

  strcpy(password, tmp);

}

int authenticate(char *str)
{
  char stored_password[15]="";
  char pass[15];
  char path[128] = "/etc/computer/Steve/password";
  int i;

  FILE *fpp; 
  int auth=0;

  fpp = fopen(path, "r");

  if(fpp == NULL)
  {
     printf("Password file %s not found\n", path);
     exit(1);
  }

  fgets(stored_password, 15, fpp);
  sanitise(stored_password);

  strcpy(pass, str);
  sanitise(pass);

  if(strcmp(stored_password,pass) == 0)
     auth=1;
  else {
     auth=0;
  }

  fclose(fpp);

  return auth; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char *envp[])
{
  if(argc < 2) 
  {
    printf("Usage: %s password\n", argv[0]);
    return 0; 
  }


  if(!authenticate(argv[1])) {
    // Log all failed attempts
    printf("Wrong password. This incident has been logged.\n");
    execute("/home/Steve/Public/error.sh"); 
    return 0;
  }

  execute("cat /etc/computer/Steve/secret");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual code? `main.c:4:8: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion
      initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'char [2]'
      [-Wint-conversion]
  char two = "\0";`. Please show a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry I made a mistake. It is char two[0]="\0". Does that make a difference?

Comment: `char two[0]` is also invalid--array size 0? Why not show the whole program that, when run, shows the result you're seeing? `char one[5] = "peter"` is also incorrect--no space for the null terminator character. Use semicolons, a `main`, etc. Thanks.

Comment: How come your compiler is not throwing warning while using double quotes in char two? It isn't a pointer. It should be be either char *two = "\0" or char two = '\0'

Comment: @ggorlen  I just added the source code for the program. The problem appears to be in th authenticate method. 
Normally, the program should check if a password is correct and then execute the file /secret. However, as long as I enter 15x 1 ("111111111111111") the secret file is opened.

Comment: @TotallyNoob you are right. my example was very simplistic. I added the source code. I am not sure if I understood the problem right. Maybe it is also a buffer overflow.

Comment: You should print the strings after you get them and after you sanitize them to help you debug.

Your fifteen ones ("111111111111111") is actually 16 characters once you include the terminating null so the strcpy() will overflow pass. I don't remember off the top of my head how strings are laid out on the stack but I suspect that extra null character overwrites the first char of stored_password, effectively nullifying it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your sanitise function puts a '\0' ,thus terminating the string, the first time it finds a non-alphabetic char value.  Are you sure that it is what you want?(Maybe you wanted to use continue; instead of break; in the for loop?)  If both the password in the file and the password the user enters start with a number, both compared strings will equal "\0". As already stated, try printing both strings before the strcmp() call.